# Run a Teradata MLOAD command in Windows command prompt, but use Python to trigger it

Tags: python, command-prompt, mload

I used to execute the MLOAD process by opening a command prompt and then typing `MLOAD < MLOAD_FILE.txt`. How do I do it using Python?

Assume that the `MLOAD_FILE.txt` is under directory `C:\\Users\\MLOAD_FILES`.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Improve formatting and language.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
import os

os.system("MLOAD < 'C:\\Users\\MLOAD_FILES.txt'")
```